# How to find all called event list in aspl.net

Tags: asp.net, debugging, trace, page-lifecycle

I have an application,Which have been multiple files and Classes written and global.asax for it. I want to debug and trace the application how the all event has been called for page.I want to trace the application how to event is called. I also tried to use Trace for it, but not able to get enough success.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function

```
Debug.Write("Type here the message you like to see");
```

from `System.Diagnostics` inside your events,

and use the [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx) from MS Sysinternals to see the messages and with this way you can have a live view what is called.

Comment: I know i can use this but their is a lot of handlers and custom classes has been written and i want to know the flow of the request, at what time which event is called of whatever class and whatever handler.

Comment: @Chandra Then you can only use an asp.net profiler.

Comment: I am trying to install ANTS code profiler to see the stack trace of the events which has been called in a request, thanks bro